# Set default response content type in Spring Boot REST API

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest

Response content type on REST API endpoints (controller classes or methods) in Spring Boot can be set using the @Produces annotation. Is there a way to set this application wide as a default for every endpoint in the REST API? For example, instead of writing @Produces("application/json") on every controller class or endpoint, can this be set on the entry application class? Or is there any other way to configure a default used until explicitely overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the default `Accept` header, not of default "Content-Type" header, so this solution will only impact `responses`, not requests.

As of Spring Boot 2.x, you need to create a class that extends the WebMvcConfigurer interface, e.g.:

```java
@Configuration
class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation( ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer){
        configurer.defaultContentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON );
    }
}
```

Let me know the result. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to specify [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data.spring.data.rest.default-media-type) *default-media-type* property in your application.properties:

```
spring.data.rest.default-media-type=application/json
```

Interestingly, it's also shown [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started.changing-other-properties) as *defaultMediaType*. I believe you can use either the above or:

```
spring.data.rest.defaultMediaType=application/json
```

I'm not sure actually why there appear to be 2 ways to specify this same property.